# Is there some way in Python where you can have a specific line of code continuing to the next?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
random_words = random.choice(str1) + '' + random.choice(str2) + '' + random.choice(str3) + '' + random.choice(str4) + '' + random.choice(str5) + ''
```

So basically I have about 27 lists named str1,str2,str3 and etc, etc which all have elements that are words. Using random.choice() I pick a random word from each list and combine them to make a random bunch of words. Although the issue which I have is how long that one specific line of code will be since im doing this for 27 lists of words. So my question is that is there some sort of way in Python where you can have a specific line of code continuing to the next? I know it sounds like a dumb question lol, but this happens often for me so I was just wondering if thats a thing. Also if its not (which it probably isn't lol), is there some sort of way that I could make this not so long? I think I can combine like 5 lists and then another 5 and then at the end add all of them together.

Comment: You can split up the line.  In some cases, like the middle of an argument list, you don't need to do anything else.  But in other cases you need to append a continuation character to the end of the first line, which is \ (backslash).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See you can either take the hard way, or choose the smart way,

> exec() function is used for the dynamic execution of Python program
>   which can either be a string or object code.

Here's what I would do instead

```
random_words = ''
for i in range(1,27):
    exec(f'random_words += random.choice(str{i}) + \' \'')
```

[Source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exec-in-python/)

Comment: I did not know about a function called exec(). Thanks a lot though, this way is much more easier and yes smarter for sure. Looks like I will be using exec() for a lot of my programs which are written like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can continue lines if you wrap your expression in parentheses. So the above would become:

```
import random

random_words = (
    random.choice(str1) + '' +
    random.choice(str2) + '' +
    random.choice(str3) + '' +
    # and so on...
)
```

Let me know if I'm misunderstanding what your question.

Answer (score 1):

First, take your 27 lists and make them a single list of lists.  Ideally, you'd just create them this way up front, but I'm going to assume you just have your 27 lists as 27 different variables (yech) and have no control over that.  That's fine; you can make your own list that will make this easier to manage.

```
word_lists = [
    str1, str2, str3, str4, str5, str6, str7, str8, str9,
    str10, str11, str12, str13, str14, str15, str16, str17, str18,
    str19, str20, str21, str22, str23, str24, str25, str26, str27,
]
```

Note that you can break that all up across multiple lines because it's inside square brackets; Python lets you continue an expression on the next line as long as you have an open set of brackets, parentheses, or braces.

Having done this once, you will *never again* need to put all of these variables in a single expression, which means you won't need to worry about super long lines of code.

Here's why: now that we have everything in a single list of lists, we can build our `random_words` in a very short iteration instead of having to copy and paste 27 different variable names again:

```
random_words = ''.join(random.choice(words) for words in word_lists)
```

Answer (score 0):

Every pyhton coder should know [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). The critical section for you is:

- [maximum-line-length](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) and rules about line-wrapping

> For flowing long blocks of text with fewer structural restrictions (docstrings or comments), the line length should be limited to 72 characters.
>   [...]
>   The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. **Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses.** These should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation.

and the continuation of that including how and when to break lines and how to continuate lines when broken using `\` as last character of the line as in

> Backslashes may still be appropriate at times. For example, long, multiple with-statements cannot use implicit continuation, so backslashes are acceptable:
>
> ```
> with open('/path/to/some/file/you/want/to/read') as file_1, \
>      open('/path/to/some/file/being/written', 'w') as file_2:
>     file_2.write(file_1.read())
> ```

Make sure to read it all - even if piecewise - because it contains lots of worthwhile information how to format code in python.